# SQL server Query Count() Optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, count, query-optimization

I am using SQL Server 2005. I am using `Count()` 3 times in my query

```
select    
    p.side,
    p.uid as uid,
    count (p.side) as cside,
    (count (p.side)/ 3) as pairs,
    ((count (p.side)/ 3) * 15 ) as commisonPrice
from  
    tempComm as p
group by 
    p.side , p.uid
order by 
    p.uid;
```

and it gives me correct output but the problem it how can I prevent by using this duplicity in my query?

Comment: Are you striving for efficiency or elegance?

Comment: for efficiency , data will increase rapidly so my main focus is on Performance , to calculate and  retrieve data efficiently

Comment: You should have put that clarification in the question. The answers you have are not more efficient than your query.

Comment: that seems to be not much efficient . . .
can you please suggest me one of the efficient way to write this query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
    side,
    uid,
    cside,
    cside/3 as pairs,
    cside/3*15 as commisonPrice 
from
(
    select
    p.side ,
    p.uid as uid , 
    count (p.side) as cside
    from tempComm as p 
    group by p.side , p.uid
) t
order by uid;
```

Comment: little explanation is also needed

Comment: So you are claiming that this is more efficient?

Comment: the question was not about efficiency but duplicity

Answer (score 2):

Couple of ways for doing it.

**1. [Common Table Expression](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/275645/CTE-In-SQL-Server) - Introduced in SQL Server 2005**

> ;WITH cte as (
>
> ```
>     select    
>           p.side,
>           p.uid as uid,
>           count (p.side) as cside
>     from  tempComm as p
>     group by p.side , p.uid
>
> )
>
> select * , cside / 3 as pairs , (cside / 3) * 15 as commisonPrice
> from cte
> order by p.uid;
> ```

**2. Derived Tables**

```
select 
    side,
    uid,
    cside,
    cside/3 as pairs,
    (cside/3)*15 as commisonPrice 
from
(
    select
    p.side ,
    p.uid as uid , 
    count (p.side) as cside
    from tempComm as p 
    group by p.side , p.uid
) t
order by uid;
```

Other ways are using temporary tables , views in which you will have to first insert data and perform further operation on columns but i don't think they are required for your question.

**Note :**

1. Both CTE and derived table can be used only once , if you require to
   perform multiple operations on your data , then use temporary
   tables.
2. Performance wise , CTE and derived table have similar performance ,
       its just matter of preference which one do you want more readable
       and undersatandable.